# htaccess rewrite url with parameters not showing images

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite urls using htaccess.

I want similar url, 
www.mydomain.com/region/category/product/

It will go to page, 
www.mydomain.com/index.php?reg=region&cat=category&prod=product

I am using the below code in htaccess,

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?reg=$1&cat=$2&prod=$3 [L]
```

Though I am able to access the parameters in index.php, but browsers are unable to load images, css etc, htaccess also rewriting urls for them.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What format are your image and CSS URLs? Are you using _relative_ URLs? If so, then anubhava's suggestion should work, however, in this case your URLs are not being rewritten. (?)

Comment: I am using, png and jpg for images, and .css stylesheets including javascripts. I tried using <base href="/" />  but it's not working. Currently I am using XAMPP in localhost and it's not under root directory. So, I couldn't understand whether it's the reason for not working.

Thanks

Comment: Finally I am able to run it using the <base href="/" /> 

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can use RewriteCond before RewriteRule statement

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css)$ [NC]
```

Comment: If the above `RewriteRule` matched then `$1` won't be the basename.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to run it using,

```
<base href="/" />
```